# tikzmark subnode in math changes font size

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I would like to annotate an equation inside a `tikzpicture`, and am trying to use `subnode` from the `tikzmark` library for this purpose. The problem is that wrapping math in `subnode` does not maintain the intended font size:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[align=left] {$A_A$ (no subnode) \\
                   $\subnode{n1}{$A$}_{\subnode{n2}{$A$}}$ (with subnode)};
\draw[<-] (n2) -- ++(0,-5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of compiled example]

This example shows subscript but other math commands such as `frac` are also affected.

How can I make the annotated equation match the unannotated one, using either `subnode` or some other command?

Comment: In the very latest version of tikzmark, which is [on github](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) but not yet on CTAN, I've made `\subnode` to be math-aware in that it ought to select the correct math level.  Since `\subnode` is the right thing to use here, if you care to test it and let me know if it works then that would be really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I have not much experience with `subnode`. Nor do I know if the following proposal is absolutely safe. I really hope @LoopSpace will tell us what one is really supposed to do here. I guess you want to read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458394/121799) carefully.

Meanwhile, this is just to report that the rather new addition to the already very nice `tikzmark` library `\tikzmarknode` makes this amazing library even more powerful. And at least in this case it seems to work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[align=left] {$A_A$ (no subnode) \\
                   $\tikzmarknode{n1}{A}_{\tikzmarknode{n2}{A}}$ (with tikzmarknode)};
\draw[<-] (n2) -- ++(0,-5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a great new command, thanks! It looks like it requires tikzmark 1.6 released just a few weeks ago (not good for overleaf and my colleagues' machines), but I `providecommand`-ed [the definition](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/blob/master/tikzmark.dtx#L1084) into my document and it works.

Comment: In the very latest version (on github), I've made subnode math-aware in the same fashion as tikzmarknode.  If you get a chance to test it, that would be amazing (and definitely worth the reputation! - I saw your comment on meta and was highly amused).

Comment: Just to say, that as `\tikzmarknode` starts its own tikz environment, it shouldn't be used inside a node.  The all-new math-aware `\subnode` command now fixes this.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of tikzmark is now available on [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) and is now in TeXLive.  This has the new math-aware version of `\subnode` in it which will match the surrounding math mode for its contents.  Your original code will work except that you shift into math mode inside the `\subnode` which you shouldn't do as `\subnode` now takes care of that itself.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459497/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[align=left] {\(A_A\) (no subnode) \\
                   \(\subnode{n1}{A}_{\subnode{n2}{A}}\) (with subnode)};
\draw[<-] (n2) -- ++(0,-5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: all new math-aware subnode]